# Moving a button that has already been created with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, function, button

Here I tried to create a JS function for creating buttons, which I have done so successfully. What hasn't worked for me, is finding a way to move/position that button within the same function. I scoured the Internet for an answer, but couldn't find one.

```js
function createButtons(dialogueString, buttonIdString) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.style.left = "50%"; //here is one of my attempts to move the button but it is not working
    btn.id = buttonIdString;
    btn.innerHTML = dialogueString;
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
};
createButtons("Hello", "choice1");
```

As you can see above, I tried using `btn.style.left` to move the button to the left, I tried writing "200px", instead of "50%" and many other stuff, but nothing has worked. If you have any idea how to solve this, please let me know, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `btn.style.position = 'absolute';` or `btn.style.position = 'relativ';`to your function

```js
function createButtons(dialogueString, buttonIdString) {
    var btn = document.createElement("button");
    btn.style.left = "50%"; //here is one of my attempts to move the button but it is not working
    btn.style.position = 'absolute';
    btn.id = buttonIdString;
    btn.innerHTML = dialogueString;
    document.body.appendChild(btn);
};
createButtons("Hello", "choice1");
```

Comment: any idea how to change the z-index of my button as well???

Comment: e.g `btn.style.zIndex = 10;`
Would be nice if you cold mark the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can make css class with
desired style and include it in js.

For example:

```
//style.css
.buttonStyle{
  color: red;
}

//javascript part
btn.classList.add("buttonStyle");
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
I did `btn.style.marginLeft = "+50px"` and it seems to work.